# How do I make the other inputs work, it only displays the result for the first choice

Tags: python

How do I make this work because when I run the code, if I input the amount of money and the cookie that I want, it just displays the result for the chocolate chip one.

```
money = int(input('How much money did you recieve? '))
cookie = input('What cookie did he/she want? ')
inventory = {
    'chocolatechip' : 50,
    'oatmeal' : 60,
    'butternut' : 65
}
if cookie in inventory:
    change = money - inventory['chocolatechip']
    if change < 0:
        print('Insufficient Cash')
        print('Please Try Again')
    else:
        print(f'Change: {change}')
        print("Thank you for buying Mark's Chocolate Chip Cookies")
        print('Please Come Again')
elif cookie in inventory:
    change = money - inventory['oatmeal']
    if change < 0:
        print('Insufficient Cash')
        print('Please Try Again')
    else:
        print(f'Change: {change}')
        print("Thank You for buying Mark's Oatmeal Cookies")
elif cookie in inventory:
    change = money - inventory['butternut']
    if change < 0:
        print('Insufficient Cash')
        print('Please Try Again')
    else:
        print(f'Change: {change}')
        print("Thank You for buying Mark's Butternut Cookies")
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes, could you please mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

You might misunderstand the meaning of the construct `if key in dict`.

With this you can check if the key is in the dictionary, so you can check if the user inputs a valid Cookie name.

Then when you are sure that the cookie exists you just use the `cookie` variable to get the price and the description from the dictionaries.

Below I provided an example code:

```
money = int(input('How much money did you recieve? '))
cookie = input('What cookie did he/she want? ')
inventory = {
    'chocolatechip' : 50,
    'oatmeal' : 60,
    'butternut' : 65
}
descr = {
    'chocolatechip' : "Chocolate Chip Cookies",
    'oatmeal' : "Oatmeal Cookies",
    'butternut' : "Butternut Cookies"
}

if cookie in inventory:
    change = money - inventory[cookie]
    if change < 0:
        print('Insufficient Cash')
        print('Please Try Again')
    else:
        print(f'Change: {change}')
        print(f"Thank you for buying Mark's {descr[cookie]}")
        print('Please Come Again')
else:
    print("No Cookies with this name")
```